# Review queues left menu bug

Tags: bug, review, design, scrolling, responsive-design

I want to report a bug in the layout in the review queues.

[image]

As you can see there is a scroll bar on the bottom, so it's not responsive. That's not the problem. When I scroll to the right, the left menu stays put and overlaps the scrolling part of the page like shown below:

[image]

Happens in Chrome 49.0.2623.112 on Windows XP (not supported), but not Firefox 47.0.2 on Windows XP. Also happens in IE 11.285.17134.0 on Windows 10 ([supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)).

Comment: Since this review queue is available on all sites, this report is on-topic here. Can we get your browser and operating system versions, please?

Comment: I'm using chrome version 49.0.2623.112 on windows xp.

Comment: That looks to be a very outdated configuration. Stack Exchange only officially supports the current and previous versions of Chrome, and Windows XP has been officially obsolete for more than four years now.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog I know an this might be the problem. I cannot update windows nor chrome because this isn't my PC. I will update the post if this issue still exist on my PC (up to date win10 & chrome) on a few hours

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog I will delete this question if the issue doesn't exist on an updated version in a few hours

Comment: @NathanTuggy But, why the menu changes its location when i scroll? ok if it isn't responsive, but It should stay where it is. right?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog: I see the same scroll-overlap problem on Win 10 IE. (Not Edge, but [IE is still officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog since the problem is not related to the chrome version nor the OS, can you please remove your downvote and delete the closing flag? thanks!

Comment: @NathanTuggy on the same PC, with FireFox 47.0.2 it works without any problem.

Comment: By the way, as I confirmed this on MSE as well, it's not SO-specific, so I took that out.